# difference between clearMockModules and removeMockModule in protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm new to Protractor. When I'm writing my script, I met some place that cannot understand the difference between removeMockModule and clearMockModules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function of `browser.clearMockModules` is to Clear the list of registered mock modules.

Function of `browser.removeMockModule` is to Remove a registered mock module.

Refer [clearMockModules](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.clearMockModules)  and [removeMockModule](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.removeMockModule)  for more information.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `remove` deletes a concrete element, that's why it receives 1 parameter, while `clear` deletes the complete list.

You can search those methods on the API reference and see that by yourself.

[API reference](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api)